# Laravel open a new tab AND change original window location

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm using Laravel 5.4, I want a form to open new tab and also change the original window location to '/'
For opening the new tab I'm using:

```
 <form Offer target="_blank" action='saveOffer' method="POST"> 
 <input  class="btn-success" type="submit" id="saveOffer" value="Save offer">
</form>
```

and its' working OK.
To change the old window location I'm using:

```
$('#saveOffer').click(function () {
    window.location.href="/"
})
```

and this is not working.
The controller works Ok in the new tab, there is a way tot change the original window location from the controller?
If I not use type="submit" the current window will change the location, but of course no more new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can change the URL using jQuery.

```
$('#saveOffer').click(function () {
  window.history.pushState('forward', null, '/');
  setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.reload();
},1000);
});
```

It will push the URL is browser history.

Comment: Thank you for such quick answer.
Now in browser I have the '/'  address but it's not loading the '/' page 
it remain the old one.
Even if I put:

    $('#saveOffer').click(function () {
        window.history.pushState('forward', null, '/');
        location.reload();
    }) 

still not load the '/' location

Comment: Instead of calling reload right after history.pushState function , call it after some time.Use the below code.
    $('.btn-success').on('click',function () {
    window.history.pushState('forward', null, '/');
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.reload();
    },1000);
});

Comment: Thank you sir!
Now it's working!
What is the explanation?